# Theme title in admin shows full path

Tags: themes

For some reason my admin panel seems to be a little busted. My themes title (Smashing Themes: Tank) now shows up as the full path of the theme instead of just he title. Kinda weird and a little annoying.  It shows up in multiple browsers.

[image: bug]

Comment: What did you do immediately before this started?

Comment: you need to post the code.

Comment: Just logged in for the first time today. Nothing special.

Comment: Post what code?

Comment: I switched themes and then switched back hoping that might fix it, but no luck.

Comment: These things don't happen from nothing. No WP or plugins update? Is this an unmodified theme or you tweaked it? [Troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) and [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). What's the code for `add_menu_page` in the theme?

Answer (score 1):

Do a project/directory wide search in your theme directory for [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and make sure second and first parameters of any calls to that function does not supply anything weird. By the looks of instead of a page name, the result of `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')` is used when setting up the menu page.

Also, if possible, try temporarily deactivating all your plugins *or* switching to different theme to verify that this is in deed caused by your theme, and nothing else.

Comment: Simon, It is definitely the theme. Switching themes resolved it temporarily, switching back and it returned. I will look into your code search suggestion and post updates.

Comment: Only two instances of the aforementioned code and both were in the admin php page. Here is a paste `add_menu_page('Theme', $name, 'manage_options', 'OptionsPage', array(&$this, 'ThemeOptionsPage'), '', 64);
   add_theme_page( $name, $name, 'manage_options', 'OptionsPage', array(&$this, 'ThemeOptionsPage'));`

Comment: The author of the theme had some updates that he did to it. I reuploaded the theme and it solved my problem. Thanks for your help in trying to diagnose.

Comment: Great! Had just about completed my answer before your comment, so I'll post it just for the record: Try logging the second parameter in `add_menu_page`, `$name` and see what it contains. Just put `var_dump($name); die();` before the call to `add_menu_page` and check the output. Somehow it seems to hold the `stylesheet_uri` rather than the menu item title like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the theme solved the problem, but thanks to Simon for his help.